# Large deviation theory exercise

Tags: self-study

I would appreciate some hints on this problem: a die is thrown ten times, use large deviation function of a Bernoulli distribution to give an estimate of the probability that the sum is 27. First it seems to me this is not a sequence of Bernoulli variables and second assuming it is how to scale the mean to be between 0 and 1?

Comment: Is that a verbatim statement of the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it: an estimation can be thought as replacing the sum of 10 independent variables by a single Bernoulli variable and scale appropriately the approximation given by the large deviation  function.

Comment: For this to be an answer, you'd have to explain how this works. It's not immediately clear that it does.